# How to interpret integration of a discontinous function

Tags: calculus, integration

My teacher says that integration of a function is the area under the curve.
But what about integration of a discontinuous function.
How do we visualize or interpret the integration of a discontinuous function like Thomae's function.[image: Here is Graph and defination of Thomae's function.]

Comment: What Lebesgue integration was born for... You might like to read the recent _The Calculus Gallery_ by William Dunham for a story on how mathematicians wrestled with functions like this through much of the 19th and the first quarter of the 20th Centuries.

Comment: I believe it has to do with (informally speaking): Rationals are countably infinite, irrationals are uncountably infinite... Hence, the point discontinuities of the rationals are insignificant in the end. Which is why the integral is zero. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: There's a passage about it in here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae's_function about halfway down the page.  Yes, the countability matters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General discontinuous functions are not integrable (consider for example a function that has a discontinuity over an interval [a,b], such that a < b), but in this case, the discontinuities are the set of all rationals. In order to integrate the thomae's function, you have to integrate the latter term (namely, x=0) over a bounded interval.

Another example: consider such a function that it equals 0 in every point that is divisible by some number and only that number, and at every other point it is the signum function of the argument. The definite integral of the function (correct me if I'm wrong) is 0 in every that is divisible by some number, and |x| in every other point.